# RuntimeError: __class__ not set defining 'AbstractBaseUser' as <class 'django.contrib.auth.base_user.Abstract BaseUser'>. Was __classcell__ propagated

Tags: python, django, django-models

1. I'm getting this error while trying to **migrate databases** after manually setting up **PostgreSQL database** for the project.
2. I was trying to **run the cloned quora project forked from github** when this error cropped up.

Follow the full error description:

```
RuntimeError: __class__ not set defining 'AbstractBaseUser' as <class 'django.contrib.auth.base_user.Abstract BaseUser'>. Was __classcell__ propagated to type.__new__?
```

Follow the trace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
          File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\quora-clone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
            utility.execute()
          File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\quora-clone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
            django.setup()
          File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\quora-clone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
          File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\quora-clone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
            app_config.import_models(all_models)
          File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\quora-clone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
            self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
          File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\quora-clone-master\env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\quora-clone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
            from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
          File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\quora-clone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
            class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
       RuntimeError: __class__ not set defining 'AbstractBaseUser' as <class 'django.contrib.auth.base_user.AbstractBaseUser'>. Was __classcell__ propagated to type.__new__?
```

Comment: Can you please, put more information about the github (if public) and about the commands that you're trying to run?

Comment: Here's the repo link.
**https://github.com/econti/quora-clone.git**
Was actually following the steps as mentioned in the repo and got stuck while managing databases.
The error might have cropped by because of databases(I think).
Or might be in setting up of environment variables.

Answer (score 24):

This approach solved my problem using `django - version 1.9.5`. Therefore, if you need to run an old Django application with new python check the following approach:

If your are using virtual environment go to: `venv/lib/Python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py`. Then, on the `class ModelBase(type):` model add the following code:

**(MAKE SURE YOU ADD ONLY THE CODE SPECIFIED)**

```
class ModelBase(type):
    """
    Metaclass for all models.
    """
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        super_new = super(ModelBase, cls).__new__

        # Also ensure initialization is only performed for subclasses of Model
        # (excluding Model class itself).
        parents = [b for b in bases if isinstance(b, ModelBase)]
        if not parents:
            return super_new(cls, name, bases, attrs)

        # Create the class.
        module = attrs.pop('__module__')
        new_class = super_new(cls, name, bases, {'__module__': module})
       
        # <========== THE CODE BELLOW SHOULD BE ADDED ONLY ======>>

        new_attrs = {'__module__': module}
        classcell = attrs.pop('__classcell__', None)
        if classcell is not None:
            new_attrs['__classcell__'] = classcell
        new_class = super_new(cls, name, bases, new_attrs)

        # <========== THE CODE ABOVE SHOULD BE ADDED ONLY ======>>

        # the rest of the class .....
```

Now, go to the directory that the file `manage.py` is located and migrate your application.

Then, `python manage.py run`.

I've got this answer from [this](https://www.programmersought.com/article/68152511237/) website.

Comment: Thanks. Will definitely try this out. One more question. I dont want to remain in django1.9. I want to upgrade old django to django3 with python3.8 and then this error happened. Any good resources wherein I can learn about migrating from old django to new django?

Comment: Just a question: are you using virtual environment?

Comment: Yes. I had setup virtual env via virtualenv module. May I ask you what effect virtualenv has on this?

Comment: I just asked just in case you've installed Django globally and it may cause issues.

Comment: This fix worked for me running a django 1.8.19 app with Python 3.9.  Seems to be working for 3.10 too as long as you update all references to the python collections' abstract classes.  In Python 3.10, the class definitions for Iterable, Iterator, Mapping, and Sequence all got moved from collections to collections.abc.  You'll have to update the django/db/models/sql/query.py, django/db/models/fields/__init__.py, and django/core/paginator.py files to update where those classes are imported from, but it does seem to work.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on? What was the problem?

Answer (score 8):

Check your python and django versions. I had the same problem and had to install a previous python with via pyenv.

Comment: the problem is basically im not more aware about PostgreSQL. so might not have properly configured the projecy..

Comment: I was using an older version of django; 1.10.5 with python 3.8. After installing Django==3.1.1, python manage.py runserver worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

###### Occurence

While installing some python package the `pipenv` (package manager) downgraded `django` version to some `1.0.x` while my python version in virtual env was `3.8.5`.

##### Solution

Reinstalled `django` to latest version `3.2.4` to match latest version of python `3.8.5`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved similar `RuntimeError: __class__ not set defining 'AbstractBaseUser' as ...` error (it was some legacy django 1.9 project) by using `virtualenv` and binding it to Python 3.6 installation:

1. Install `virtualenv`:

   ```
   pip3 install virtualenv
   ```
2. Download old Python 3.6 and install it with minimal options (only pip checkbox and no "Add to PATH" in options) to some path (I used that django project directory itself, `/my_django_project/python36` for example).
3. Create virtual environment, binding it to old python:

   ```
   cd /my_django_project
   virtualenv --python=./python36/python.exe venv
   ```
4. Activate virtualenv:

   ```
   .\venv\Scripts\activate
   ```
5. Install old `django==1.9` (and other packages when necessary):

   ```
   (venv) pip install django==1.9
   ```
6. Launch django backend in activated virtual environment:

   ```
   (venv) python manage.py runserver
   ```

Comment: great. will update once im done running mine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

upgrade Django version

> pip install django --upgrade

Answer (score -5):

Consider this line

```
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
RuntimeError: __class__ not set defining 'AbstractBaseUser'as<class'django.contrib.auth.base_user.AbstractBaseUser'>. Was __classcell__ propagated to type.__new__?
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear what you want to achieve. Have a look here => [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)